# Git - Merging Branches

Tags: git, merge, branch

I was reading this [post](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#feature-branch-workflow), and there's something that I don't know if I got it wrong.

Let's say I'm in the *master* branch, and another developer is working on a feature, and he's working in a separate branch called *newFeature*.

If I'm in my *master* branch, and I pull the *master* branch, and then his *newFeature* branch, do they merge automatically? What I mean is I don't have to do

> $ git merge newFeature

Instead, these would be my commands:

```
$ git checkout master #We move to master branch.
$ git pull origin master #We pull the master branch to sync.
$ git pull origin newFeature #We pull the newFeature branch.
```

Since I'm in *master* branch, and I'm pulling that other branch, do they merge automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend avoiding the `pull` command entirely.  It simply runs two commands for you: `git fetch`, which is simple, safe, and straightforward; and then another command that you should—at least conceptually—choose based on the result of the fetch.  But you must choose that command *in advance*, before you see the result of the fetch.  For this and other reasons, `git pull` is a bad tool, like a chainsaw that starts by itself as soon as you fuel it up, even if you're not actually ready to use it yet.  Sure, it *seems* convenient, until you saw off a finger or two... :-)

That said, the second command that `git pull` runs is indeed normally `git merge`.  (You can configure it to run `git rebase` instead, and there are several other corner cases as well where it may not run `git merge` after all.)  The precise arguments it passes to `git merge` is/are a bit tricky, especially because some of the flags you can pass to `git pull` are flags to `git fetch`, and others are flags that are only meaningful for `git rebase`, and there are some flags that *are* useful in `git merge` that you *cannot* pass through `git pull` at all: yet another way it's not a very good tool.

Hence, the simple expansion of these three commands is not *exactly* the same, but it is close enough: you are running:

> ```
> git checkout master
> git pull origin master
> git pull origin newFeature
> ```

which means that the five command that Git actually executes are:

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
git fetch origin
git merge origin/newFeature
```

(since `git pull` just runs two Git commands).

Note that one of these `git fetch` commands is probably pointless: there's no reason to fetch twice in rapid succession.  The `git fetch` step obtains any new commits that are available on another Git, which your Git is calling `origin`.  The `git merge`-s merge the updated `origin/master` and `origin/newFeature`, one at a time (this is almost certainly what you want), into your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you are bringing the work of `newFeature` to the branch where it is located, remember that if you do not want to bring all the work `newFeature` you can also bring the commit.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @torek absolutely.
To answer to original question:
The two branches are NOT automatically merged if/when you simply `git pull` each.  It performs a "merge" operation *with respect to that branch* but will not alter any other branch (e.g. master).

Comment: "with respect to that branch" in this context means "it will merge with its upstream branch which is likely origin/master and origin/newFeature respectively". However you can also specify which branch to merge with in which case "git pull origin newFeature" will merge from "newFeature" into the checked out branch, which is "master". Actually, "git pull origin master" also "overrides" which branch to pull from in the remote but this is likely the same as the upstream branch anyway.